# CommandButton not calling actionListener when I close confirmDialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, actionlistener

I have buttons Stop and Release which call a save method and within the save method a confirmDialog is shown. I can use the Stop button, press OK in the dialog and the method works, but then when I go to clock Release again the button doesn't call the actionListener. Similar for clicking Release, confirming then trying to Stop.

Here are the two command buttons, which sit inside modeControls.

```
<p:commandButton title="Stop" value="Stop"
        rendered="#{unitSetVehicleStatusBean.crudMode == 'READ' and unitSetVehicleStatusBean.stopped =='false'}"
        actionListener="#{unitSetVehicleStatusBean.stop}"
        update="modeControls :mainForm" 
        process="@this :mainForm"/>
<p:commandButton title="Release" value="Release"
        rendered="#{unitSetVehicleStatusBean.crudMode == 'READ' and unitSetVehicleStatusBean.stopped =='true'}"
        actionListener="#{unitSetVehicleStatusBean.release}"            
        update="modeControls :mainForm" 
        process="@this :mainForm"/>
```

Here is the confirmDialog. The save method it calls is called from within the stop() and release() methods, then after some validation I use

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext
                        .getCurrentInstance();
                context.execute("PF('saveNDTDialog').show();");
                break;
```

and when the user selects OK in the confirmDialog it will rejoin this method part way through a switch statement and complete the save.

Here is the confirmDialog.

```
<p:confirmDialog id="saveNDTDialog" appendTo="@(body)"
            widgetVar="saveNDTDialog" closeOnEscape="true"
            closable="true"
            message="#{message.stoppedValidationNDTWarning}">
            <p:commandButton value="OK"
                update="mainForm :modeControls"
                actionListener="#{unitSetVehicleStatusBean.save('WARNING_NDT')}" 
                oncomplete="saveNDTDlg.hide();"/>
            <p:commandButton value="Cancel"
                onclick="saveNDTDlg.hide();" />
        </p:confirmDialog>
```

I believe the issue is something to do with the appendTo or possibly onComplete, but aren't too sure what's going wrong.

Any suggestions welcome...

Comment: Just to add. If I remove the call of the confirmDialog and run straight through the save method, the Stop and Release buttons work perfectly.

Comment: I believe dialog.hide() i deprecated in PF5 (or is it 5.1). Unless you're on something old I would do as you do in the java method. Also I think that "saveNDTDlg" is wrong unless you have several dialogs

Comment: Yeah I'm on PF4. There are several dialogs, I just gave an example of one of them to make it easier to follow. I've got it working now though, will explain in answer..

Answer (score 0):

By pulling the dialog out of the main form and adding a form around the commandButtons in the dialogs, the dialogs began working as expected.

Comment: There is more than one post about this in the PrimeFaces forum. I'm curious if you searched there and what terms you used. Just to see if I can try to 'tag' posts there with some comment so in the future they will be found. And btw, this is also mentioned in the PrimeFaces documentation

Comment: Yes I had searched and tried this once, but it hadn't worked. I believe it didn't work because of of oncomplete="saveHDTDlg.hide()" which I changed to omcomplete="PF('saveNDTDialog').hide();"